# Need a tip for the study of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n!^{1/n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How should I proceed? What kind of criteria should I apply in this situation?

i tried this thing not really sure if its ok

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n!^{1/n} > \sum_{n=a}^\infty a^{n^{1/n}} = \sum_{n=a}^\infty a = \infty$
where $a \ge 1$

Comment: What is a necessary condition for a series to converge?

Comment: Look for a minor series that diverges.

Answer (score 6):

If $x\geq1$ then $x^{1/n}\geq1$ for every natural $n$. In particular $n!^{1/n}\geq1$. This tells you that the general term doesn't converge to $0$ so the series must diverge.